# MSSQL to distribute rows into static number of columns

Tags: sql-server

I can't figure how to write a mssql select to distribute results from a single table into a static number of multiple columns, let's say 3.

Example of a existing table data:

```
select item,qty from Table1

item1 qty1
item2 qty2
item3 qty3
item4 qty4
item5 qty5
item6 qty6
item7 qty7
```

Desired output (no matter the order):

```
  item1 qty1    item2 qty2    item3 qty3    
  item4 qty4    item5 qty5    item6 qty6
  item7 qty7    item8 qty8
```

Tried with pivot but it outputs always only one item per row, doesn't look the right solution.

Comment: If the columns have no *meaning* in terms of the data that is placed in each one, it would be **far** better to do this at the presentation layer (e.g. code that *consumes* this data or report builder, or whatever)

Comment: what will be the data in the above pivoted columns>

Comment: What are you trying to do? The shape of the desired data is meaningless to anyone but a human. It's **far far** easier to create a wrapping item list eg in HTML with Bootstrap - it's simply a matter of setting the proper classes to the tags

Comment: In fact I need to show them up in a SSRS report, but for the same reason I can't figure out how to display like that

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that it *can* be done but probably shouldn't be<sup>1</sup>:

```
declare @t table (item varchar(19) not null,qty varchar(17) not null);
insert into @t(item,qty) values
('item1','qty1'),
('item2','qty2'),
('item3','qty3'),
('item4','qty4'),
('item5','qty5'),
('item6','qty6'),
('item7','qty7'),
('item8','qty8');

WITH Numbered as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item) + 2 as rn
    from @t
), Positioned as (
    select item,CONVERT(varchar(19),qty) as qty,rn%3 as col,rn/3 as rw
    from Numbered
), Combined as (
    select col,rw,type,value
    from Positioned
        unpivot (value for type in (item,qty)) t
), Labelled as (
    select rw,type + CONVERT(varchar(9),col) as finalcol,value
    from Combined
)
select *
from Labelled
    pivot (MAX(value) for finalcol in (item0,qty0,item1,qty1,item2,qty2)) u;
```

Result:

```
rw                   item0               qty0                item1               qty1                item2               qty2
-------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
1                    item1               qty1                item2               qty2                item3               qty3
2                    item4               qty4                item5               qty5                item6               qty6
3                    item7               qty7                item8               qty8                NULL                NULL
```

The CTEs are as follows - `Numbered` assigns row numbers to each row, because just because you want things to be arbitrary doesn't mean that SQL is as happy to do so. We then, in `Positioned` convert those row numbers into column (`col`) and row (`row`) coordinates.

Having decided where everything is to be placed, we need to prepare for the final `PIVOT` operation - by `UNPIVOT`ting all values to be pivotted into a single column (`value` in `Combined`).

From there, in `Labelled` we can combined the original column names (`type`) with the columns that have been selected for them.

In the final query, we combine all of this information in a final `PIVOT` to create the desired set of columns.

---

<sup>1</sup>Because this sort of display/presentation logic really belongs in a language or tool *designed* for presentation concerns, rather than deep down in the bowels of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      item VARCHAR(10) ,
      qty VARCHAR(20)
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'item1', 'qty1' ),
        ( 'item2', 'qty2' ),
        ( 'item3', 'qty3' ),
        ( 'item4', 'qty4' ),
        ( 'item5', 'qty5' ),
        ( 'item6', 'qty6' ),
        ( 'item7', 'qty7' );

WITH  cte AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY item ) - 1 ) % 3 AS rn ,
                        ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY item ) - 1 ) / 3 AS gr
               FROM     @t)
    SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN item END) itemA ,
            MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN qty END) qtyA ,  
            MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN item END) itemB ,
            MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN qty END) qtyB ,
            MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN item END) itemC ,
            MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN qty END) qtyC
    FROM    cte
    GROUP BY gr
```

Output:

```
itemA   qtyA    itemB   qtyB    itemC   qtyC

item1   qty1    item2   qty2    item3   qty3
item4   qty4    item5   qty5    item6   qty6
item7   qty7    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

`rn` gives position of columns. `gr` gives grouping sequence.

```
item    qty     rn  gr

item1   qty1    0   0
item2   qty2    1   0
item3   qty3    2   0
item4   qty4    0   1
item5   qty5    1   1
item6   qty6    2   1
item7   qty7    0   2
```

So you are grouping by `gr` and distribute columns by `rn`.